# Authentication and Authorization for API Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-security-oauth2, api-gateway

I am building an Api gateway in springboot with microservices and would like to implement all features/principles of API Gateway

1. Authentication/Authorization
2. Routing (Able to route using spirng cloud gateway)
3. Load balancing (Netflix Ribbon)
4. Cache Management
5. Rate Limit
6. API Performance monitioring

I have explored to implement authentication/autherization using OAuth2 but couldn't find suiltable solution.

Looking for suggestions or examples to implement the features.

Gone thru https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-security-oauth-example, its nice

Answer (score 4):

You can refer this [repo](https://github.com/Nasruddin/student-course-registration-system-service) for most of your requirement. I have added security using Spring security. Zuul is used for gateway service. Project also include Eureka for service discovery. Implementing Caching should be fairly simple with this repo. You can also find other repositories in my [GitHub profile](https://github.com/Nasruddin) which will help you implement remaining features using spring.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code, Its look nice. 
How or From where could i start testing? All urls from localhost:8762/** are unauthorized.
I guess the flow start from Gateway, Do you have written any documentation on auth-service?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't written any documentation yet, but I look forward to do it soon. As of now you use  http://localhost:8762/auth with request body { username: "user", password: "password" } to login which will return you the user object with JWT token. All subsequent protected URL can be accessed by setting Authorization header with generated token. If you need more help you can directly ping. Feel free to fork the code and contribute.

Comment: Thanks, It helps!, I changed the path to route to StudentController as   routes:
    course-service:
      path: /v1/students in gateway

Comment: Hi @Nasruddin I saw your project its fantastic it cover  basic skeleton of spring-boot microservices, Can you share some link or project skeleton if you have used ```Spring API Gateway ```instead of using ```Zuul ``` how can I replace it with or if you can guide.

Comment: Hi @ParthTiwari I have done that but haven't pushed to my GitHub repo.  Will do it soon. Btw thanks for the comment :)